# A Plague Tale: Requiem: Unreachable Chest (Bug?)

Tags: a-plague-tale-requiem

There is a chest hidden in the fishing village (Chapter VII, Felons) in A Plague Tale Requiem.

I have tried everything I can to try and reach it. I cannot find it referenced in any guide, nor can I see any reports that it is a bug in the game.

In the fishing village, find this hut:

[image: Ther village is on the right in this picture. Enter it.]

Inside it, is this chest:

[image: This image cannot be reached as far as I can tell.]

Can it be reached? If so, how?